# how to change time name every 5 minutes

Tags: javascript, node.js, settimeout, setinterval

I made a whatsapp bot using **[Baileys](https://github.com/adiwajshing/Baileys/)** and made a werewolf game feature, I want the time to change every 5 minutes from morning to night then morning again like a loop until the winner is determined. I use **setInterval** but it causes spam

I also used **[Node Corn](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-cron)** and the result is the same

**the all_room json db**

```js
[
{
"code":"FJ32Q",
"group_id":"6288742689173-1610938001@g.us",
"time":"morning",
"night":0,
"status":"starting",
"vote":false
}
]
```

**getTime (function to get time from db)**

```js
const getTime = (group) => {
let alldb = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync('./database/ww/all_room.json'))
satu = alldb.find((obj => obj.group_id == `${group}`));
return satu.time
}
```

**set_time (functon to change value)**

```js
const set_time = (times, group) => { 
let alldb = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync('./database/ww/all_room.json'))
satu = alldb.findIndex((obj => obj.group_id == `${group}`));
alldb[satu].time = times
fs.writeFileSync('./database/ww/all_room.json', JSON.stringify(alldb))
}
```

```
if(isWS(group.id)){ // true
  setInterval(() => {
    if(getTime() === "morning") { 
      set_time("night")
      reply("the sun is setting be careful because the werewolves are starting to roam")
    } else if(getTime() === "night") {
      set_time("morning")
      reply("the sun has risen")
    }
  }, 300000);
}
```

**Result**

this is even spam

[image: result]

Comment: the result image is not visible. By spam do you mean the changes are happening in less than 5 mins ?

Comment: Can you add the code for `set_time` and `get_time`?

Comment: @eol done, can setinterval run two different functions using if and else ?